# How can I access file downloaded using RSelenium in Github Actions?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, github-actions, rselenium

I have a test repo in GitHub and I am using GitHub Actions to visit a URL and download a .zip file, using RSelenium and a Docker container running Selenium Firefox. As shown in the code below, I run the Docker image, and I have set up the volumes so that the `download` folder in my repo is "connected" to the `/home/seluser/Downloads` where Firefox downloads the .zip file in the Docker container:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: main

jobs:
  testFlow:
    # The type of OS
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-firefox:111.0-20230328
        ports:
          - '4444:4444'
        volumes:
          - /github/workspace/data/downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads

    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
          
      # Load repo and install R and renv
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          r-version: 'renv'
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-renv@v2

      - name: Install libcurl
        run: sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

      # Run R script
      - name: Script
        run: Rscript scripts/test.R
```

I have tested the following the `test.R` script locally and it works: the .zip file is downloaded in the container and it appears in the `downloads` folder in my system. However, when running it on GitHub, it correctly connects to the website but nothing is downloaded. What am I doing wrong? Here is the script I'm using to test it:

```r
fprof <- RSelenium::makeFirefoxProfile(
  list(
    browser.download.dir = "/home/seluser/Downloads"
  )
)

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = "firefox",
  extraCapabilities = fprof
)

dir.create(here::here("data", "downloads"), recursive = TRUE)

remDr$open(silent = TRUE)

remDr$navigate("https://demo.borland.com/testsite/download_testpage.php")

Sys.sleep(5)

print(remDr$getTitle())
print(remDr$getCurrentUrl())

remDr$findElement("xpath", "//tr[@filename='Small.zip']//td")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("xpath", "//button[@id='downloadButton']")$clickElement()

remDr$close()

print(list.dirs("data", recursive = TRUE))
print(list.files("data", recursive = TRUE))
```